# Initializing vector in fortran 95

Tags: fortran

I am using a external program that is run by a script. The script require a direction vector to be specified - this is how programs manual describes it:

```
real(kind=dp) :: direction(3)
```

So when running the program script I specify:

```
direction = (/0.5,0.5,0.5/)
```

The program yields an error saying it can't read the direction vector - could you tell if I am doing something wrong or this is actually a bug. Thank you.

Comment: The script is provided with the program. It is a name list and requires adding the direction in it manually. Have no info about syntactical correctness.

Comment: Ok - it should have had 0.5 0.5 0.5 instead. Thanks, High Performance Mark for telling about the name lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
direction = (/0.5,0.5,0.5/)
```

is syntactically correct for a Fortran statement to set the values of the `direction` array.  But it is not syntactically correct in a namelist file.  In such a file either

```
direction = 3*0.5
```

or

```
direction = 0.5,0.5,0.5
```

is correct.

Comments turned into an answer not for vainglory but so that future generations will find a question answered.